# add condition to boolean, is it posible?

Tags: javascript, angular

What I'm trying to do is create a true/false condition programatically, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

It should be something like:

```
bool: boolean = (data1 === "1" && data2 === "2")


if(condition) {
  boolean = bolean + "|| data3 !== 3)
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: You can just assign the conditional result to a variable. `result = (data1 === "1" && data2 === "2")` then use that variable in the next condition. `if (result || data3 !== 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just add it like you would with an if clause, as such:

`newBool = oldBool && (condition)`

or with or clause

`newBool = oldBool || (condition)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a result with concatenating a string (actually not desired to use `eval`), but you can do

```
myVar: boolean = (data1 === "1" && data2 === "2");

if(condition) {
   myVar = myVar || data3 !== 3;
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
(data1 === "1" && data2 === "2") || data3 !== 3
```

with only one difference that `(data1 === "1" && data2 === "2")` is already evaluated during the assignment.